# Why won't my node / Heroku app connect to RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-rds

I am migrating to RDS from Heroku PostgreSQL. For my RDS, I have set:

`Availability Zone  us-east-1e`

When I try to connect to the DB from my app though, I get

```
2017-02-13T16:11:09.087276+00:00 app[scorebot.1]: Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: connect ETIMEDOUT ip.ad.re.ss:5432
```

I can connect to that IP from my home computer. So why can't I do it from Heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the endpoint DNS name supplied by RDS instead of an explicit IP address. That DNS name may resolve to a different IP address internally in AWS (where Heroku is running) versus remotely on your local server. You should be using that DNS name anyway in case your RDS server has a fail-over event, at which point the IP address is subject to change.

I assume you have the "Publicly Accessible" flag enabled on the RDS instance since you can connect from your local computer. You also need to check the security group assigned to the RDS instance. If you only allowed your local IP address in the security group, then connections from Heroku would be blocked.

Comment: I am using the DNS `mysite.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432`. I do have `Publicly Available` checked, so I'm not sure why I can't connect

Comment: OK, what does your RDS security group look like?